# How to use \addtocontents to indent to section/subsection names 

Tags: sectioning, table-of-contents, indentation

```
\chapter{C}
\section{S}
\subsection{SS1}
\subsection{SS2}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{AddedSS}
```

results in

```
1  C ................... 1
   1.1 S ............... 1
       1.1.1 SS1 ....... 1
       1.1.1 SS2 ....... 1
       AddedSS ......... 1
```

But I would like to get added manually subsection `AddedSS` to be indented to subsection names, like this :

```
1  C ................... 1
   1.1 S ............... 1
       1.1.1 SS1 ....... 1
       1.1.1 SS2 ....... 1
             AddedSS ... 1
```

How to achieve this to added manually subsection?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{C} \section{S} \subsection{SS1} \subsection{SS2}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{\protect\numberline{}AddedSS}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great ! It works ! How did you know it ? I tried `texdef -t latex -f \subsection`, but the only thing I've found : `\long macro:->\@startsection {subsection}{2}{\z@ }{-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}{1.5ex \@plus .2ex}{\normalfont \large \bfseries }` what told me nothing.

Comment: Well how I learned it is lost in the depth of time. But the obvious location to see how numbers are formatted is the toc-file.

Comment: Please add some explanation along the code as it might not be clear to everyone what you did and why.